# Classes in AngularJS - fields and methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say that I am defining following class to be used in my AngularJs code:

```
app.factory("exampleClass", function () {
    // constructor
    function exampleClass(val) {
        this.prop1 = val;
        this.result = "";
    }

    // methods
    exampleClass.prototype = {
        doSomething: function (userVal) {
            this.result = this.prop1 + userVal; // any way to avoid this?
            console.log(this.result);
        }
    };

    // return class
    return (exampleClass);
});

// .. later in code
new exampleClass("another").doSomething("321");
console.log(scope.example.prop1);
```

Is there any way to evade referencing class fields (prop1 and result) with this. in doSomething method, while still being able to reference them from outside of class directly? Obviously I am trying to emulate something like `public type fieldName` in other modern languages - when this. is not present first look in instance variables?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. JavaScript (in the current versions supported by browsers at least) does not support automatic property access from methods.

It is *theoretically* possible to get the syntax you want with trickery involving `with()` or local variables and `Object.defineProperty`, but it will end up making the rest of your code much uglier.

For a more feasible way to get better syntax for JavaScript there's multiple languages out there that compile into JavaScript. One example if [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) which supports property access with a Ruby-esque `@foo` syntax.